How to have nested constraints in jakarta validation
My team is currently migrating from PHP to Kotlin. In PHP we have the following custom constraint:
class Bid {
    #[Assert\AtLeastOneOf(
        [
            new Assert\Range(min: 0, max: 12), 
            new Assert\Range(min: 14, max: 15)
        ]
    )]
    private int bidGroup = 15;
}

So either one of those range constraints must be valid for the bid group to be considered valid. We have other places where also different constraints are mixed so it is not always a Range constraint.
The idea is to have the same in kotlin:
class Bid {
    @AtLeastOneOf(
        [
            Range(min = 0, max = 12),
            Range(min = 14, max = 15)
        ],
        message = "The value should be between 0 and 12 or between 14 and 15"
    )
    var bidGroup: Int = 15
}

I now tried to implement this in kotlin but have issues defining the annotation:
import com.myCompany.validation.validator.AtLeastOneOfValidator
import jakarta.validation.Constraint
import kotlin.reflect.KClass

@MustBeDocumented
@Constraint(validatedBy = [AtLeastOneOfValidator::class])
@Target(
    AnnotationTarget.FIELD,
    AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION,
    AnnotationTarget.ANNOTATION_CLASS,
    AnnotationTarget.CONSTRUCTOR,
    AnnotationTarget.VALUE_PARAMETER,
    AnnotationTarget.TYPE,
)
annotation class AtLeastOneOf(
    val value: Array<out Constraint>,
    val message: String = "",
    val groups: Array<KClass<out Any>> = [],
    val payload: Array<KClass<out Any>> = []
)

The out Constraint does not work as constraints neither implement nor extend anything they only have a meta annotation Constraint.
Is there any way how I can have any kind of constraint as a parameter for another constraint?
I already worked a full day on this and tried out different classes. The only remaining idea I had was to add own constraints like com.myCompany.validation.constraints.Range which extends the jakarta Range and also implements a common interface which I could use for the value parameter. But I don't consider this a good solution.
As a last resort I even asked ChatGPT but it could not solve the issue either.
